# How to add "distinct on" from postgreSQL in golang squirrel lib

Tags: sql, postgresql, go

I want to get top 1 from each group, but not by PK, so I have to use distinct on. But there is no function DistinctOn in [squirrel library](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/Masterminds/squirrel@v1.5.2), only Distinct without arguments. So what can I do if I want to use this library?

I have tried function prefix that inserts its argument before select.
I expect something like:

```
select distinct on (name, age) name, age, city from people where name='John'
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to convert the query to a self-join on `(name, age)`? Somethng like `select name, age, city from people where (name, age) in (select distinct name, age from people)`

Comment: Isn't it expensive to make a self-join?

Comment: I'm not a PG expert but 1) I would say _this_ self-join should be a no-brainer to the optimizer ;-), and 2) it's easy to verify using `EXPLAIN`.

Comment: (Please tag people you're responding to using `@`–like `@kostix`, otherwise they won't get notified by SO.)

Comment: Does select `select name, age, max(city) from people where name='John' group by name, age` work too?

Comment: @jarlh no, I can't group by, because I get this error: ```must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function```

Comment: My GROUP BY query above wouldn't cause that error. Are you perhaps selecting more columns than described?

Comment: The above self join query will return all rows... (At least as long as no null values are involved.)

Comment: @jarlh yes, I am, so I cant use group by

Comment: Then you can use a window function. Give us a [mcve], to make problem clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This comment](https://github.com/Masterminds/squirrel/issues/24#issuecomment-60032455) in the [issue #42](https://github.com/Masterminds/squirrel/issues/24) «DISTINCT ON (postgres only)» hints at using the `Options` method.

Using it, we can get the desired SQL statement–the program

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    sq "github.com/Masterminds/squirrel"
)

func main() {
    query := sq.Select("name", "age", "city").
        Options("DISTINCT ON (name, age)").
        From("people").
        Where(sq.Eq{"name": "John"})

    fmt.Println(query.ToSql())
}
```

Prints:
`SELECT DISTINCT ON (name, age) name, age, city FROM people WHERE name = ? [John] <nil>`
which looks sort of what was expected.